# Probability to find a particle in a particlar state $\psi_{n}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability

I have a problem to understand the probabilities in QM. In particular, if I have a particle in state $\psi_{n}$, then we change the system and we ask for the probability to find the particle in a state $\varphi_{n}$. Where $\psi_{n}$ are the stationary states of the system 1 and $\varphi_{n}$ of the system 2.

When I talk about changing the system, it's for example if we have a harmonic oscillator system with a constant electric field and then we remove the electric field. I understand it have something to do with $|c_{n}|^2$, where $c_{n}$ is:

\begin{equation}
c_{n}=\langle{\psi_{n}|\varphi_{n}}\rangle=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\psi_{n}^{*}\;\varphi_{n}\;dx
\end{equation}

I understand the mathematics of the situation. My problem is really to understand the physics of this situation. If I could simply list my questions, it would be like that:

1. What are the probabilities of being in a stationary state?
2. What are the probabilities of being in a state (it could be a linear combination of several stationary states)?
3. What are the probabilities of being in a state after the system changes?
4. How can I use the equations to help me to understand the probabilities in the system or systems?

Comment: Your title was excellent. It asked about the probability of finding a certain outcome. Your questions are 100% different, they are about the probability if being which is different. When you measure you change your state and change it into an eigenstate of the observable. Your language needs to allow that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quantum system is described by a set of self-adjoint operators $(A_1\ldots A_n, H)$ and a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. The mentioned operators represent the observables that you can experimentally measure and their eigenvalues the possible outcomes. Among them there is a special one, the Hamiltonian $H$, describing the time evolution of the system. A state is any element $|\psi\rangle \in \mathcal{H}$.

> What are the probabilities of being in a state (it could be a linear combination of several stationary states)?

Assumptions provide that any state can be expanded onto a basis of eigenvectors of any of the observables, namely $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i c_i |a_i\rangle$. This means that *after having performed a measurement* of the observable $A$ your state can become any of its eigenvectors (namely any of its possible outcomes), collapsing into them with frequencies of $|c_i|^2$ if performing *infinite* measurements.

> What are the probabilities of being in a stationary state?

It is not clear what you mean by stationary state. Any system changes in time, thus nothing is stationary. What can happen is that after a measurement of the energy your initial state becomes an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian (by definition of measurement); if so, and if the time evolution operator is diagonal onto the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian, then a subsequent measurement of the energy will give back the same state because the eigenvectors remain such.

> What are the probabilities of being in a state after the system changes?

Given the initial state $|\psi_{\textrm{in}}\rangle$ and the time evolution operator $U(t)$, the state after "the change" (as evolution) will be $U(t)|\psi_{\textrm{in}}\rangle = |\psi_{\textrm{final}}\rangle$. The probability of this being any other state $|\phi\rangle$ after infinite measurements is $|\langle\phi|U(t)|\psi_{\textrm{in}}\rangle|^2$.

Comment: Where you write *a measure* do you mean *a measurement*?

Comment: Ooops, yes, a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Sorry to nag but there's a couple more of these where *measure* should be *measurement*.

Comment: My bad, done now.

Comment: This seems more clear to me now, but I wasn't introduce to the operator $U(t)$ before or I was but it wasn't introduce that way. I would like more precision about $U(t)$.

Comment: @WernerSpin Finding the form of the time evolution operator $U(t)$ is, unless you fall into some special cases, quite difficult. You can either look up the complete derivation or open a new question about it.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco What is the definition of the 'infinite measurement' at the last line of your answer? Also can you please suggest me a reference where I can find the quantum mechanical description in the rigorous way you have put?

Comment: The last line is to be intended as "after an infinite amount of experiments"; as for the references, any standard textbook in quantum mechanics as, say, Messiah, Griffith, Sakurai, Cohen-Tannoudji.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is saying much the same as Gennaro, but I'd phrase things slightly differently.

In config $\mathbf{1}$ your system has some eigenfunctions $\psi$, and you start with the system in one of these eigenfunctions $\psi_n$.

When you change to config $\mathbf{2}$ the function $\psi_n$ is no longer an eigenfunction because your system now has a set of different eigenfunctions $\varphi$. However we can express the function $\psi_n$ as a linear combination of the new eigenfunctions:

$$ \psi_n = \sum_i c_i \varphi_i $$

So your system is now in a superposition of lots of different eigenfunctions. In effect you have just set $\psi_n$ to be the initial state of your system. You could have chosen any function as the initial state - $\psi_n$ just happens to be the initial state inherited from the pre-change state.

To extract information you just proceed as usual. For example if you want the energy you simply use:

$$ \langle E \rangle = \langle \sum_i c_i \varphi_i | \mathcal{H} | \sum_j c_i \varphi_j \rangle $$

and because the $\varphi$ functions are orthonormal this expands to:

$$ \langle E \rangle = \sum_i c_i^2 E_i $$

As you say in the question the constants $c_i$ are calculated using:

$$\begin{align}
 c_i &= \langle \varphi_i | \psi \rangle \\
     &= \langle \varphi_i | \sum_j c_j \varphi_j \rangle \\
     &= \sum_j c_j \langle \varphi_i | \varphi_j \rangle 
\end{align} $$